Issues while converting a site with PHP Html and css to React and PHP, especially the PHP implemented in HTML
Yesterday I decided to try react so I can use my site on mobile too and the problem is that I have too many PHP code I used along with HTML like this one:
<div class='post'>
    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "forum_topics") or die(mysqli_error());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics ";
    $records = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
        echo "<a class='none' href='$filename'>";
        echo "<div class='display'>";
        echo "<p>Posted by ❚ ".$row['topic_poster']."</p>";
        echo "<p><strong>#</strong> ❚ ".$row['topic_rel']."</p>";
        echo "<img src='images/".$row['topic_photo']."'>";
        echo "<div class='smalltext'><p>".$row['topic_post']."</p></div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</a>";
    }
    //      echo "<img src=".$row["topic_photo"]["tmp_name"]. " >";
    ?>
</div>

Appareantly I cannot use php code in JSX (As I know I have to convert html to jsx). People told me to use json_encode and then fetch() in react but I don't know how to use them with multiple arrays coming from the database. I just need to do the same thing that my current code does with react and php only
I was not able to try anything since I could not workout the way of using the json related methods

What you're describing is essentially re-implementing your entire website to a new structure in a new technology stack.  You would want to start with some tutorials on React and begin to build your application, separating front-end UI functionality (React) from back-end data functionality (PHP, exposing web services that return JSON to be invoked by AJAX calls from the client-side code).  There's no quick fix we can give you that would absolve you from learning the technologies you're trying to use.

Agreed. This is a fundamental re-write, not just a quick fix where you can convert bits and pieces directly. It's going to involve a completely different application structure and design, not just a direct translation from one language to another.

People told me to use json_encode and then fetch() in react but I don't know how to use them...then you're going to need to learn, otherwise you won't be able to achieve anything towards your stated goal. At Stackoverflow we can help you with specific programming issues, but we can't teach you new technologies or replace you entirely when you completely lack the relevant skills - this isn't a code-writing service, and "I just need" isn't a question. See also [ask] and the [tour] to learn more on that.

Any suggestions for the sources that I can use to learn react. Their documents were very narrow

P.S. so I can use my site on mobile too...are you talking in terms of making a native mobile app? Because of course you can access any website on mobile through your browser. It might not have a responsive design which makes it easy to use on mobile, but that is something you could potentially fix without completely rewriting it from scratch.

Stackoverflow doesn't provide recommendations for tutorials and so on either - see What topics can I ask about here? to learn what you can / can't ask, and why you can't ask that. Asking for recommendations tends to attract spam or commercial promotions which are hard to tell apart from genuine advice, and also we're not a research service.

@user20617578: The vendor provides guidance.  Your favorite search engine can also help you find other tutorials and learning materials.

In your refactor, it sounds like you're going for a PHP/MySQL back-end and a React Client.
Example repo: react-client-php-server-example
People posting in the comments on your question are correct; you cannot mix PHP and React together. PHP is a server-side language, and React is a JavaScript library. It uses JSX which needs to be transpiled into JavaScript and in this case would run client-side in the browser.
Your PHP/MySQL backend should now just query the database and serve JSON data:

<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // normally you'd restrict this to your client's domain
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); // script should send back JSON

// Pseudo-code for querying the DB for topic data...
// $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "forum_topics") or die(mysqli_error());
// $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics ";
// $result = mysqli->query($conn, $sql);
// $topics = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// for now I'll just hard-code some topics...
$topics = [
  [
    'id'           => 1,
    'title'        => 'Topic 1',
    'slug'         => 'topic-1',
    'topic_post'   => 'This is topic 1',
    'topic_photo'  => 'https://placehold.co/600x400',
  ],
  [
    'id'           => 2,
    'title'        => 'Topic 2',
    'slug'         => 'topic-2',
    'topic_post'   => 'This is topic 2',
    'topic_photo'  => 'https://placehold.co/600x400',
  ],
  [
    'id'           => 3,
    'title'        => 'Topic 3',
    'slug'         => 'topic-3',
    'topic_post'   => 'This is topic 3',
    'topic_photo'  => 'https://placehold.co/600x400',
  ],
];

echo json_encode($topics); // encode and respond with JSON
exit;


On the client side in React, you'd make a fetch request to your PHP backend for the JSON data. Fetching data from an API is considered a side-effect, so should be handled in a useEffect hook.
Once the fetch request completes, you can set it into your component's state, causing it to re-render and display the JSX.

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  // state to hold topics data
  const [topics, setTopics] = useState([])

  // fetch topics on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTopics()
  }, [])

  // function to fetch topics from the PHP backend
  const fetchTopics = async () => {
    try {
      // make a fetch request to your php endpoint
      const response = await fetch('http://yourserverdomain.com/all-topics.php')
      const allTopics = await response.json()
      // set topics JSON into state
      setTopics(allTopics)
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>All topics</h1>
      {topics.length === 0 // if no topics fetched
        // show loading indicator
        ? <p>Loading...</p> 
        // when component re-renders with results, map through them and return your JSX
        : topics.map(({ id, title, slug, topic_post, topic_photo }) => (
          <div href={`/topic/${slug}`} key={id}>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <img 
              src={topic_photo}
              alt={`Photo for ${title}`}
            />
            <p>{topic_post}</p>
          </div>
        )
      )}
    </main>
  )
}

export default App


Note: This separate client/server approach is good for Single Page Applications, but horrible for SEO. Nowadays there are ways to server-render your React components, but that is a topic for another Stack Overflow question.

I will try this today and later on i can try something different.

I knowi it has been a few weeks but i took some react courses to be able to read your code better. There is a weird issue im facing. Which is, cmopiler says that I have to put an ',' between topics.length instead of the dot

That's great, @user20617578! Sounds like you found more good resources out there.
Not sure why it would be telling you that. topics,length is not valid JS code. topics.length is valid because Arrays always have a length property.
Could you post the code snippet? It might help to be able to see it and spot if there isn't actually a different issue with the code.

{posts.length === 0 ? <p>Loading</p> :        posts.map(({ name, title, url, body, date, conf, collect }) => (         <div class='post'>         <h2>{title}</h2> <h4 class='email'>Posted by {name}</h4>         <a href={url}><img src={conf} alt='img' /></a>         <p>{body}</p>         </div>       ))     }

That looks fine to me, @user20617578. It should work, though you should put a key prop on your outermost div. Use some unique data like an ID or the url:
<div class='post' key={url}>. Whatever compiler you're using may be incorrect. Stick with posts.length. posts,length with a comma is not valid JS.
